# car vibrating only at 80-90 mph

Tags: automatic-transmission, suspension, dodge, vibration, charger

I have a Dodge Charger 5.7 2016 (automatic transmission)

It shakes (the car) at 80-90 mph

its not like body problem no the car actually shakes a little if i remember correctly

the steering wheel does not shake

I can also feel the vibration
in the throttle and brake pedal

the vibration happens even when
gas or brake is not pressed

however at 90 mph when brakes are
applied the car shakes even more
violently

the problem started
after I repaired things in front

I am not sure if they are suspension
related but i think they repaired rods or something (replacement) because my car used to make strong sound upon sudden break (now gone)

back to present problem, I tried braking strongly at low speed I didnt notice abnormalities

I tried revving in neutral no abnormalities

I balanced the wheels but that didnt fix the problem

and My front and rear tires performed alignment and caster adjustment procedure respectively

Its a mystery where the problem is;
my rear tires are fresh new and the front ones slightly unevenly worn on inner side

again, steering wheel does not vibrate and brakes and throttle pedals also vibrate a little during the vibration

ps: car service due this week

appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did the vibration start when the new tires were put on the back or was it happening before that? Also, from your description, it seems like you might have two problems and not one: vibration at speed; vibration when braking (under certain circumstances).

Comment: By the way, going 80-90 mph is not weird in the wide open American west.  Most of the freeways are signed for 80, with a few 85s.

Comment: Front end damage? To what extent? Are engine mounts ok? Driveshaft and couplings ok?

Answer (score 0):

Vibration not felt in the steering wheel but felt in the brake pedal can indicate an issue with the rear brakes. If the vibration worsens in the brake pedal when brakes are applied I would look at the rear brake discs and check if they need to be turned/replaced.